# How do i make a list of objects that are a child of the list's data type?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public ArrayList<CheckingAccount> getCheckingAccounts(){
    ArrayList<CheckingAccount> list = new ArrayList<CheckingAccount>();
    for(int i = 0; i < this.accounts.size(); i++){
      if(this.accounts.get(i) instanceof CheckingAccount){
        list.add(this.accounts.get(i));
      }
    }
    return list;
}
```

"accounts" is an ArrayList of all Account objects. I'm trying to make a separate Array list of all CheckingAccount objects (which extend the Account class).

Comment: what problem you are facing here with this code?

Comment: You need a cast: `list.add((CheckingAccount) this.accounts.get(i))`. You should also learn to use the foreach loop, and streams.

Comment: Line 5 is trying to add an Account object to a CheckingAccount ArrayList. I'm trying to make an ArrayList of CheckingAccounts, but I'm taking from an ArrayList of Accounts which is a parent of CheckingAccount.

Comment: You need to cast as suggested by @JBNizet

Comment: @AveryGovier what Samarth is trying to tell you (AFAIK), is that when you ask about a compilation error, you should post the compilation error. Not just post the code without telling what the problem is. Once you realize that reading the error message is the first step in fixing the error, you also realize that simply googling for the error message usually gives you the solution.

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet. That fixed my problem wonderfully.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah the same thing I was asking.